# Limit and offset in Android SQLite query

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, limit, offset

I have a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper. There I have a getCursor() method. I can't make LIMIT and OFFSET work. No matter what numbers I throw, it always returns the same values. How can I make it work?

```
public Cursor extraeCursor() {
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(contexto);
        String query= "";
        boolean favoritos = pref.getBoolean("favorite",false);

        String offset;
        switch (pref.getString("limit", "1")) {
            case "1":
                offset = Integer.toString(MainActivity.numPage * 1);
                query = "SELECT * FROM lugares limit 1 offset " + offset;
                if (favoritos) query = "SELECT * FROM lugares WHERE favorite = 1 limit 1 offset " + offset;
                break;
            case "2":
                offset = Integer.toString(MainActivity.numPage * 2);
                query= "SELECT * FROM lugares limit 2 offset " + offset;
                if (favoritos) query = "SELECT * FROM lugares WHERE favorite = 1 limit 2 offset " + offset;
                break;
            case "3":
                offset = Integer.toString(MainActivity.numPage * 10);
                query= "SELECT * FROM lugares limit 10 offset " + offset;
                if (favoritos) query = "SELECT * FROM lugares WHERE favorite = 1 limit 10 offset " + offset;
                break;

        }
        SQLiteDatabase bd = getReadableDatabase();
        return bd.rawQuery(query, null);
    }
```

Comment: Your queries seems right, did you try to set offset manually? Doest it provide same result?

Comment: How can I offset manually?

Comment: I mean just try query = "SELECT * FROM lugares limit 1 offset 1"; and query = "SELECT * FROM lugares limit 1 offset 2"; will it get same results? Because probably your problem is with other code, not in query.

Comment: Yes. I get the same values. Now I really dont know where the problem is

Comment: Did you try query= "SELECT * FROM lugares limit "+offset+",10; ?

Comment: Still the same. No matter what numbers I write

Comment: Unique ids are the same? Because if yes we need exorcist here

Comment: I have 12 elements inside my DB. No matter what offset or limit I choose, I always get the first 10 items. All this items have different _id (which is their unique key)